# Elan Touchpad Physical Buttons Drag but not click

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus, synaptics, libinput

I have an Elan Touchpad on an ASUS ROG G752VL which has both tap to click and phyical left and right buttons. Using Synaptics driver, the touchpad works very accurately. However, the left phyical button does not appear to act like it should (the right physical button does not work at all on libinput or Synaptics). It cannot be used to click, but it can be used to drag. When I use libinput instead of Synaptics, this issue is fixed. However, libinput has very horrible accuracy and acceleration with my touchpad. Is there any way I can get the best of both worlds?

Running `xinput` with Synaptics driver

```
Device 'Elan Touchpad':
Device Enabled (153):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (276): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (277):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (278):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (279):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (315):  136, 3287, 96, 1697
Synaptics Finger (316): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (317):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (318):   170
Synaptics Tap Durations (319):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (320):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (321):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (322):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (323):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (324): 77, 77
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (325): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (326):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (327): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.051760, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (328):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (329):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (330):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (331): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
Synaptics Click Action (332):   1, 3, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (333): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (334):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (335): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (336):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (337): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (338):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (339): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (340):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (341): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (342):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (343):  0
Synaptics Gestures (344):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (345):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (346): 32, 32
Synaptics Area (347):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (348):  1711, 0, 1470, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (349): 19, 19
Device Product ID (270):    1267, 19
Device Node (271):  "/dev/input/event14"
```

Running `xev` when dragging with Synaptics driver

```
MotionNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
root 0x1c9, subw 0x0, time 3600099, (164,145), root:(192,228),
state 0x100, is_hint 0, same_screen YES
```

Running `xinput` with libinput

```
Device 'Elan Touchpad':
Device Enabled (153):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (301): 1
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (302): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (303):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (304):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (305):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (306):   0
libinput Accel Speed (289): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (290): 0.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (270): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (271):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (272):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (294): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (295): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (296):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (297):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (298):   1, 0, 0
libinput Click Methods Available (307): 1, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled (308):    0, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled Default (309):    1, 0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (310):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (311):    0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (312):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (313):    1
Device Node (273):  "/dev/input/event14"
Device Product ID (274):    1267, 19
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (288):   <no items>
libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (275):    1
```

Pressing left physical button and using `xev` with libinput driver

```
ButtonPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
root 0x1c9, subw 0x0, time 167865, (89,120), root:(117,203),
state 0x0, button 1, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
root 0x1c9, subw 0x0, time 167960, (89,120), root:(117,203),
state 0x100, button 1, same_screen YES
```

Holding down left button and moving mouse

```
MotionNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
root 0x1c9, subw 0x0, time 273321, (85,134), root:(113,217),
state 0x100, is_hint 0, same_screen YES
```